# length is not working correct in twig

Tags: arrays, twig

Below is my category array containing sub arrays and I want to find length of sub-array of each category array item.

```
[category] => Array(
[0] => Array(
    [name] => Desktops
    [children] => Array(
        [0] => Array(
            [name] => PC
            [children3] => Array()
            [column] => 1
            [href] => http://192.168.0.101/user1/opc_laddylike3.0/upload/desktops/pc
            )
        [1] => Array(
            [name] => Mac
            [children3] => Array()
            [column] => 1
            [href] => http://192.168.0.101/user1/opc_laddylike3.0/upload/desktops/mac
            )
        )
    [column] => 1
    [href] => http://192.168.0.101/user1/opc_laddylike3.0/upload/desktops
    )
[1] => Array(
    [name] => Laptops & Notebooks
    [children] => Array(
        [0] => Array(
            [name] => Macs
            [children3] => Array()
            [column] => 1
            [href] => http://192.168.0.101/user1/opc_laddylike3.0/upload/laptop-notebook/macs
            )
        [1] => Array(
            [name] => Windows
            [children3] => Array()
            [column] => 1
            [href] => http://192.168.0.101/user1/opc_laddylike3.0/upload/laptop-notebook/windows
            )
        )
   [column] => 1
   [href] => http://192.168.0.101/user1/opc_laddylike3.0/upload/laptop-notebook
 )
```

)

I want to find length of children of category array. Please check my code and help if I am wrong.

```
{% for category in categories %} 
{% if category.children %}
{% for n in 0..(category.children|length) %}
```

Here I am getting category.children length as 1 for all array items.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try storing category.children|length in a different variable and using it? {% set x = (category.children|length) %}
{% for n in 0..x %}

Comment: Thank you.
Yes,I did. But still not working

Comment: I tried copying the same array, I get the length as 3 
{% for category in categories %}
    {% if category.children %}
        {% set count=1 %}
        {%  for n in 0..(category.children|length) %}
            {{ n }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

This prints 0 1 2 0 1 2 for me

Comment: [2] => Array ( [name] => Components [children] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => balls [children3] => Array ( ) [column] => 2 [href] => mouse ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Monitors [children3] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => test 1 [href] => monitor/test1 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => test 2 [href] => children3] => Array ( ) [column] => 2 [href] => printer ) [3] => Array ( [name] => Scanners [children3] => Array ( ) [column] => 2 [href] => scanner ) [4] => Array ( [name] => Web Cameras [children3] => Array ( ) [column] => 2 [href] =>  ) ) [column] => 2 [href] =>  )

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28671386/how-to-check-a-multidimensional-twig-array-for-values

Comment: Please use above array to test

Comment: i try in [this twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/ub9mhg) without any problem... check the variable names