# How can I use a twig attribute in a multidimensional array?

Tags: arrays, symfony, attributes, twig

I am accessing dynamic data from an array:

```
{% for key, value in columns_arr %}
  {% for k,v in group %}
    var {{ value }} = "{{ attribute(v, value) }}";
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This is working well for `name` and `id` (see below). In the example of `name` the attribute ...

```
{{ attribute(v, value) }}
```

is replacing:

```
{{ v.name }}
```

and in the example of `id` it is replacing ...

```
{{ v.id }}
```

But this is not working with `type` because here I actually need to replace:

```
{{ v.type.name }}
```

So my question is, how would this look like in the attribute function?
I tried `{{ attribute(v.name, value) }}` but I get the error

> Impossible to access an attribute ("type") on a string variable
>   ("ID").

group:

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => Fields {#7444 ▼
    -id: 1
    -name: "ID"
    -unique_id: "6ab8c870ed"
    -productgroup: PersistentCollection {#7448 ▶}
    -type: Type {#7525 ▼
      +__isInitialized__: true
      -id: 2
      -name: "hidden"
      -unique_id: "5e1086c862"
      -label: "hidden"
       …2
    }
  }
  1 => Fields {#7526 ▶}
  2 => Fields {#7530 ▶}
  3 => Fields {#7534 ▶}
]
```

columns_arr:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "id"
  1 => "name"
  2 => "type"
]
```

My approach according to this question:

[How to check a multidimensional Twig array for values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28671386/how-to-check-a-multidimensional-twig-array-for-values)

```
{% for key, value in columns_arr %}
  {% for k,v in group %}
       {% for k1,v1 in v %}
          var {{ value }} = "{{ attribute(name, v1) }}";
       {% endfor %} 
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But this gives me an error, My page is not loading anymore.

Another approach is this:

```
{{ attribute(v, [value.name]) }}
```

But I get the error:

> Impossible to access an attribute ("name") on a string variable
>   ("type").

Comment: Would you be able to change the column array to something like `2 => "type.name"`?

Comment: @DarkBee  Probably an idea! I will check it out and let you know, thank you

Comment: @DarkBee I was able to create an array with "type.name"!

Comment: I'm assuming `var type.name` will not be valid javascript. I'd suggest replacing the dot with something else `var {{ value | replace({ '.' : '_', }) }}; `

Comment: I actually need to remove `.name` again from `value`, you know?

Comment: `{{ value | split('.') | first }}` would do that

Comment: Thank you! I will check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to change the column array to something like `2 => 'type.name'`, you can use the following snippet to read out nested data:

```
{% for value in data %}
    {% for column in columns %}
        {% set output = value %}
        {% for method in column|split('.') if method != '' %}
            {% set output = attribute(output, method) | default('') %}
        {% endfor %}
        {{ output }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/oe3u00)

Comment: I will check it now!

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I get the error message: `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given").`

Comment: I'm assuming you have your arrays the other way around, so you would need to split `value` and not `v`. I'm using the `data` array as first array and the columns as second

Comment: I gues because `var {{ value }}` is now inside a second loop. Possible?

Comment: Don't forget you need to reverse the `output` variable as well. `{% set output = v %}` - [source](https://twigfiddle.com/qk2z4y)

Comment: Please edit your question with the updated code. It's unbearable to read code in the comment section

Comment: Ah, I think I know, because `value` is now `type.name`. It has to be `type` here `var {{ value }}`...

Comment: oh my god, was a stupid mistake. finally found it. `var {{ value | split('.') | first }} = "{{ output }}"` was the solution